# Slack slash command not visible in the channel

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am developing a Slack bot using Bolt API in Node.js. The problem I am facing is when I send a slash command, the bot receives and responds to the command successfully but the command is not visible in the channel.

I read the following article https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#responding_response_url where it states that I need to add `{"response_type": "in_channel"}`

**slack.js**

```
const { App, LogLevel } = require("@slack/bolt");
app.command("/ask", async ({ command, ack, say, respond }) => {

    console.log("command ", command)
    console.log("ack ", ack)

    await ack();
    await say(`Hi <@${command.user_name}>`)

    
})

(async () => {
    const port = 8000
    await app.start(port);
    console.log(`⚡️ Slack Bolt app is running on port ${port}!`);
   })()
```

I am new to slack API, and I am not able to understand how should I manipulate the request in order to see the commands in the channel as well

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding it to your `ack({"response_type": "in_channel"})`, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `respond` command in order to send a message that is visible within the channel:

```
await respond({"response_type": "in_channel", "text": "hello!"});
```

There's an example of this within the Bolt for JavaScript docs here: https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#action-respond

Comment: This doesn't work. Here are the replies with hello, I am not able to see when the user sends the command. As soon as the user sends the command the bot says hello!

If you look at this  https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#responding_response_url here as the user sends /weather it is visible in the channel, I want to achieve that.